# Approximate discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, discrete-data

I have a discrete probability distribution with can take a large number of discrete values, say $x \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$. I know $p(x)$ for all these $x$. Typically, quite many of the values have a small probability $p(x)$, and are therefore not very relevant when I want to do further operations with this distribution (like computing the means for functions of $x$, but also other inferential operations). What I want to do is to approximate the distribution $p_0(x)$ by a distribution taking only $N_0 \ll N$ number of discrete values, which I can then use to get approximations to the various operations.

I have a few options:

1) Sampling with replacement from $p(x)$ until I get $N_0$ unique numbers, and then creating $p_0(x)$ based on the sampled frequencies of the unique $x$.

2) Just use $x$ with the $N_0$ largest probabilities, and set $p_0(x)$ proportional to $p(x)$ for those values.

I am pretty sure 1) would lead to unbiased estimates of say means etc., but it just feels very inefficient to throw away the original $p(x)$.

Method 2) feels much more efficient when computing say a mean, but I guess it being deterministic may lead to biased estimates.

Any thoughts about what would be the best approximation $p_0(x)$ to $p(x)$, taking only $N_0$ distinct values?

Any pointers to methods or literature to look into is also highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I will just add some additional information to my problem, which may or may not help you answer my question.

Let $S = \{1,\ldots,N\}$ and $S_0 \subset S$ be the subset of the approximate distribution taking $|S_0|=N_0$ unique values.

Although it is not the only thing I want to do, we can assume that for some function $h$, which is very expensive to evaluate, I want to estimate $E[h(X)] = \sum_{j=1}^N h(x=j)p(x=j)$ by $\sum_{j \in S_0} h(x=j)p_0(x=j)$ for some $S_0$ and $p_0$.

Further, $N=2^K$, where $K$ is the number of distinct probabilities that $p(x)$ takes. You may think of this as $K$ different groups of different sizes. The large groups have relatively small probabilities compared to the small groups. Note however, that the values $h(x)$ may in theory be very different within each group. Thus, just evaluating $h(x)$ for a single $x$ within each group, say, and using that value for all $x$ within that group, is probably not a good idea.

Without knowledge about $h$, I am thinking that I need an approximate distribution which "covers" as much of the original distribution as possible, that is an $S_0$ where $\sum_{x \in S_0} p(x)$ is as large as possible, and still being (close to) unbiased. I might be looking at this the wrong way though...

Comment: In both cases you seem to be assuming that the values that didn't appear via sampling on among largest $N_0$ (both approaches are in fact equivalent) have $p_0(x)=0$..? This does not seem to be a reasonable assumption...

Comment: Is it necessary that the new set of $N_0$ distinct values be a subset of the old values or can they be from a set of values I choose?

Comment: @Tim: I agree that this is an assumption in both cases. While it may not be a perfect assumption, it is, as far as I can tell, the only way to reduce the number of distinct values. Agree?

Comment: @Glen_b: I guess that could form a subset of value of your choosing. However, the main reason I want to do this is that it is expensive to perform any evaluation involving $x$. I am therefore not sure how grouping values would help... 
I will update the question to make my intentions clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have set of possible values $x \in S$ of size $|S| =N$. Because of some computational issues, you want to make $N$ much smaller by somehow "ignoring" the values of $x$ that come with small probability $p(x)$.

The simple solution that comes to my mind, is to select subset $S_0$ of the $N_0$ values that come with largest probabilities, and for all the other values assume *same* probability, that is equal to the average their probabilities. Now your distribution $p_0$ is defined in terms of $N_0+1$ unique probabilities:

$$
p_0(x) = \begin{cases}
p(x) &\text{if}& x \in S_0 \\
c &\text{if}& x \in S -S_0
\end{cases}
$$

where $c=\frac{\sum_{x'\in S -S_0} p(x')}{N-N_0}$ is a constant. This makes $p_0$ exact for the most probable values, and approximate otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. It is good idea, but I wonder how I could compute say $E[h(x)]$ under this approximation?

Comment: @Mark same as with $p(x)$, you take $E[h(x)] = \sum_x p_0(x) h(x)$.

Comment: This requires evaluation of $h$ at every $x$, which it pointless to do the approximation in the first place (see the edited question)... Right?

Comment: @Mark I missed the edit. Given the edit, it seems that your question is not at all about approximating the distribution, but rather about calculating expected value, isn't it?

Comment: No, I want to do different inferential things with the distribution. Computing the expected value is just one such thing, which I though would make the question a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

You could just collapse the probability of groups of adjacent values of $x$ to single points.

If you let $N_0 = \lceil N/k\rceil$ for some $k \geq 2$, then you can have $p(y_i) = \sum\limits_{j=i\cdot k + 1}^{j_{max}} p(x_j)$ for $i \in \{0, \dots, N_0-1\}$, where $j_{max} = \min(N,\,(i+1)\cdot k))$.

It's fast and doesn't throw away any probability.

Comment: This is bad if high probable points are close to each other.

Comment: @gunes it depends on what exactly does OP expect and how does his data look like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Taking the computation of say $E[h(x)]$ as a example, this approach seems to assume that $h(x=j)$ and $h(x=j+1)$ are similar, which they might not be. And what value should I use for $y_i$ when evaluating a function?

Note also that I updated the question with some more information. Using this approach on the $K$ groups would make sense, but again the $h(x)$ may not be similar and I don't know how to choose a representative $x$ for that group when evaluating $h$.